Что использовать вместо устаревшего Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles?

microsoft.aspnetcore.staticfiles устарел, что использовать вместо?

они (методы из этого пакета) после 3версии встроенны, добавьте строку app.UseStaticFiles(); либо в Program либо Startup

а что есил стартап отсутствует?

какой проект у вас //Program.cs -а тоже нету?

он то есть и метод этот внутри него, просто гайды видел и там  присутствал проект Startup, а у меня его почему то нет.

Это нормально, если Startup отсутствует в новых проектах, потому что начиная с .NET 6 появилась минимальная модель программирования, в которой Startup.cs больше не обязателен. Вместо этого вся конфигурация приложения теперь может быть размещена прямо в Program.cs. У меня тоже его нету.

и метод этот внутри него => доступ есть к методам пакета StaticFiles ? //пакет не нужен значит, так тоже можно все использовать https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0
